# How i can get all files?

Tags: ruby, input, upload, sinatra

I upload 3 files in my input but in my zip i have only 1.Can someone explain why ? ( first time in ruby)

this is my code :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'zip'


    post "/upload" do 
#      0.upto(params.length) do
      @file_ext = File.extname(params['myfile'][:filename])
      if @file_ext != ".exe"
        return "Pas un fichier exe"

      else

        input_filenames = (params['myfile'][:tempfile].read)
          zipfile_name = "File-AGS/test/archive.zip"

          Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
            zipfile.get_output_stream(params['myfile'][:filename]) { |os| os.write input_filenames }
          end        
          return "ok"
      end
#        end
    end
```

Comment: Can you debug `input_filenames`? Does it have all uploaded files?

Comment: Hi, i found my error, " params['myfile'][:tempfile] " need " [i] ' after "  params['myfile'] "